# Searching An NSArray of NSDictionaries

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

If I NSLOG() the array that I'm trying to search I get this...

```
(
    {
    id = 101323790;
    "screen_name" = AmyBurnett34;
},
    {
    id = 25073877;
    "screen_name" = realDonaldTrump;
},
    {
    id = 159462573;
    "screen_name" = ecomagination;
},
    {
    id = 285234969;
    "screen_name" = "UCB_Properties";
},
    {
    id = 14315150;
    "screen_name" = MichaelHyatt;
}
)
```

This is fine but what I need to do is to be able to have a method that lets me put in an id and then it returns the matching screen_name as an NSString. How could I do this is the array is called.

I think NSPredicate is what I'm looking for but I'm not sure...

```
NSArray *twitterInfo;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, NSPredicate is what you want. Something like this:

```
NSString yourID; // assume this contains the id you want
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id = %@", yourID];
NSString *screenName = [[[twitterInfo filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred] lastObject] objectForKey:@"screen_name"];
```

Comment: That returns nothing it says my array is empty

Comment: @TheMan: I just whipped up a test to make sure I'm not going crazy and it worked perfectly. It seems like you must have the wrong data somewhere. Difficult to tell what's going wrong without more info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm partial to using enumeration with blocks (easier to understand than predicates :-):

```
NSInteger desiredID = ...;
__block NSString *userName;

NSString *name = [twitterInfo enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *dict, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
{
  NSInteger theID = [[dict objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
NSLog(@"Check ID %d against %d", theID, desiredID); // just to see its working
  if(theID == desiredID) {
    userName = [dict objectForKey:@"screen_name"];
    *stop = YES;
  }
} ];
```

If userName is nil at the end of this, the id was not found.

Comment: If you think that boilerplate-heavy 10-line loop is easier to understand than a one-line predicate, I think maybe you just haven't given predicates a fair shake.

Comment: :-) YMMV. Apple keeps telling devs at WWDC that blocks are much faster and code is smaller. The nice thing about above is it can become a lot more complex quickly - try doing that with the predicates. An really the above Predicate is like a format statement - its not the real string - it has to get interpreted first, only then is the real predicate created. In any case, you get to choose the tool that works best for you - I've been using the enumerations more and more and am very happy with them. YMMV as they say !